# How can I make live Parallel Coordinates Plot that could show labels for the lines on hover?

Tags: visualization, outlier, plotting

I'm using parallel coordinates plot for visualization of my outliers. Is there a way to create them so as to show some information(another column content) about the lie on hovering?
Plotly has interactive graphs for Parallel Coordinates Plot but they seem to have different functions than this.

Comment: Could you add the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: A data sample would be nice as well.